# HTML5 datetime attribute in <time> element

Tags: html

Consider the two code samples below from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time).

What is the difference? When should I use `datetime` attribute
 or simple enclose the date and time within `<time>`?

```html
<p>The concert took place on
  <time datetime="2001-05-15T19:00">May 15</time>.</p>

<p>The concert took place on
  <time>May 15,2001 at 7:00 pm</time>.</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-time-element)

> The time element represents its contents, along with a machine-readable form of those contents in the datetime attribute. The kind of content is limited to various kinds of dates, times, time-zone offsets, and durations, as described below.
>
> The datetime attribute may be present. If present, its value must be a representation of the element's contents in a machine-readable format.
>
> A time element that does not have a datetime content attribute must not have any element descendants.

More information here: [Microformats Datetime Design Pattern](http://microformats.org/wiki/datetime-design-pattern)

Comment: So, if I am just using time tag with no datetime attribute , the value written by between those tags also have to match YYYY- MM -DD etc pattern ? Or we can write in plain english ?

Comment: Pls have a look here : https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-time-element. Here, the spec mentions 2 points:  1) The datetime value of a time element is the value of the element's datetime content attribute, if it has one, otherwise the child text content of the time element. 2) The datetime value of a 'time' element must match one of the following syntaxes. So, does not this shows we cannot write in plain english if we are not using datetime attribute ?

Comment: @Breaking Benjamin: As it says, if the element has a datetime attribute, then the content is free-form, because only the datetime attribute has to satisfy that condition, if it is present.

Comment: @BoltClock, yes but my question is when I am not using datetime attribute ? Then what ?

Comment: @Breaking Benjamin: Then the content has to satisfy the condition.

Comment: Hi again - the link I gave gives the exact valid strings you can use. The datetime is only used by crawlers or other specialised software/plugins if at all used

Answer (score 0):

The datetime attribute is used to clarify the date, the text of which is between the  tags. It's not visible, but can be read programmatically.